# How to Monitor Redis Metrics on Grafana while Telegraf is Running on Docker's Container on localhost?

Tags: docker, redis, localhost

I am trying to monitor Redis metrics on Grafana while my telegraf is running inside Docker's containers. Both Redis and Docker are running localhost.I am facing belew error while looking into telegraf's logs inside container.Kindly help me to resolve this.

**[inputs.redis]: Error in plugin: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: connect: connection refused**

Already updated the "Inputs.redis" in "telegraf.conf" file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the host's IP address, since `127.0.0.1` is the container itself, and not the host's IP.

The IP from the `docker0` interface on the host is accessible from the container, ty using that.

I'm considering that :

- `redis` is running in the host at port `6379/tcp`;
- `telegraf` is running inside a container at the same host